# Выбор нужного testNG.xml в jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, testng

Имеется проект (Java + Maven + TestNG). Создана job в jenkins. В Build Goals and options `clean install -DtestNGxml=TEST-156_TestNG.xml`
В TEST-156_TestNG.xml добавлены 3 сьюта

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
```

```
<suite-files>
    <suite-file path="TEST-156_OMNI_TestNG.xml"/>
    <suite-file path="TEST-156_OSS_TestNG.xml"/>
    <suite-file path="TEST-156_SHOPP_TestNG.xml"/>
</suite-files>
```

Вопрос, можно сделаь, чтобы при старте job был выбор, какой suite запускать. Зарание спасибо

Answer (score 0):

реализовал так, в jenkins Build Goals and options `clean install -DtestNGxml="$xml"`. В This project is parameterized - добавил выбор параметра, вполе Name ставим xml, в поле  Choices - собсвенно наши

```
TEST-156_1_TestNG.xml
TEST-156_2_TestNG.xml
TEST-156_3_TestNG.xml
```